# tablednd and rm_script.js error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tablednd

I have this part of code in my functions.php:

```
function cc_admin_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
    $file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_register_script('my-upload', $file_dir."/functions/scripts/rm_script.js",array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox','farbtastic'));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('tablednd', $file_dir.'/functions/scripts/jquery.tablednd.js', array('jquery'), '0.5');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-draggable' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cc_admin_enqueue_scripts');
```

Everything works fine. The rm_script javascript works ok, except I got this error notification in IE:

> Object doesn't support this property or method rm_script.js line 290

in the rm_script.js line 290:

(this is where line 290 starts:)

```
jQuery(".table_sort").tableDnD({
    onDragClass: "myDragClass",
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
    var $multitable_wrap = jQuery('.table_sort .multitable');
    $multitable_wrap.each(function(i) {
    var $current_sub_table = jQuery(this);
    $current_sub_table.find('.correct_num').each(function(){
    var $newname = jQuery(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/,i);
    jQuery(this).attr({'name': $newname,'id': $newname});
        });});},
    onDragStart: function(table, row) { }
});
```

the jQuery(".table_sort").tableDnD is the source where I got an error. If I delete it, it works just fine, but I need it to support my javascript function.
I've declared the jquery.tablednd.js, but somehow .tableDnD function couldn't be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's apparently a jquery load problem.
 Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error saying that jQuery doesn't support this property or method, it means that the tableDnd code hasn't been loaded properly.

The first thing to check is that the URL for jquery.tablednd.js is correct in this file and actually being loaded (you can do this by copying the relative URL and pasting it into the address bar of IE--ensuring that you allow for any relative paths).

I'd be surprised if that wasn't the problem. If you still do have the problem, is it just limited to IE, or does it affect other browsers? If you use FireFox (with FireBug) or Chrome and look at the console you might be able to find out more precisely what's going wrong.